# How to loop through a specific depth in an array?

Tags: php, recursion, iteration

I'm pulling JSON information and I'm left with a huge nested array.

An example schema is as follows:

```
'messages' =>
    '0' => 
        'title' => 'foo'
        'body' => 'bar'
    '1' =>
        ...
'stories'
    'foo' => 'bar'
```

In this scenario, I only want to grab contents from starting with '0' and '1' and all of their children (title and body). 'stories' would be completely disregarded as it is one depth higher than 0 and 1. 0 and 1 is an automatically generated list and the integer value will dynamically go as high as need be, so it will be different.

Cheers!

Comment: Are they always going to be numbers followed by a word, and it's always going to be the word that you don't want (plus anything below the word)

Comment: @popeygilbert it's always going to be numbers, and I want all of the numbers children

Comment: So you want to iterate through all elements of the array, recursively, and catch everything which index are numbers 0 and 1?

Comment: ... and only at a specific depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array['messages'] as $key => $val){
    if($key == 0 OR $key == 1){
        $new_array[] = $val;
    }
}
```

`$new_array` will then have the relevant content.  This assumes that you're referring only to the `messages` part of the array.  If there are other sub arrays that you want to parse/manipulate then you will have to adjust the condition in the foreach loop.

You can then parse/manipulate `$new_array` as needed, and ignore the content that you don't need in `$array`.